# devextreme datagrid command button

Tags: jquery, html, datagrid, devextreme

I am using devextreme grid view. 
is there any way to add a custom command button besides defualt command button?
i have tried this code but i think this is not the correct way.

```
onContentReady: function (e) {
            if ($("#createButton").length == 0) {
                var $customButton = $("<a id='createButton' i />")
                  .text("Users")
                .addClass("btn")
             .on('dxclick', function () {
                 var url = '@Url.Action("sample")';
                 window.location.href = url;
             });
                var toolbar = e.element
                  .find('.dx-link');
                $(toolbar.get())
                   .prepend($customButton);
            }
        },
```

Comment: As far as I understand you are looking for something like this - [Toolbar Customization](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Data_Grid/ToolbarCustomization/jQuery/Light/)

Comment: @Sergey yes somthing link this. but its customize the header but i want to add an extra btn to command button.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using html and jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var r = $('<label class="className" type="button" onclick="yourFunction()" >Custom Name</button>');
    $('#gridId.dx-toolbar-before').append(r);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are looking for something like this code.

```
              onContentReady: function (e) {
            if (!e.component.detayColumnAdded) {
                e.component.detayColumnAdded = true;
                e.component.addColumn({
              cellTemplate: function (cellElement, args) {
             $('<a/>').addClass('dx-link')
           .text('Detay')
           .on('dxclick', function (info) {
                        }).appendTo(cellElement)
                    }
                });
            }

        }
```

Also

```
        columns: [
           { cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
            $('<a/>').addClass('dx-link')
            .text('CLİCK')
            .on('dxclick', function (info) {

            })
            .appendTo(container);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing workaround in angular: adding a normal column and change template

```html
<dxi-column cellTemplate="cellTemplate" caption="Edit" ...>
  <div *dxTemplate="let cell of 'cellTemplate'">
    <div><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></div>
  </div>
</dxi-column>
```

then catch wit `onCellClick`event:

```js
onCellClicked = (e): void => {
 if (e.column.caption === 'Edit') {
   this.OpenMobile.emit(e.data);
   return;
 }
}
```

read more about [cellTemplate](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#cellTemplate)

and [onCellClick](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onCellClick)

so you can implement this useful trick whatever the framework.