# Devextreme dxDataGrid inside dxDataGrid editing

Tags: javascript, devextreme, dx-data-grid

I have a problem about Devextreme..

I want to show dxDatagrid on dxDatagrid - editing popup.

I just want when I clicked 'Edit' show popup and dataGrid inside popup

In react, I Although success like this

[image: **enter image description here**]

```
          <Item>
            <DataGrid
              dataSource={employees}></DataGrid>
          </Item>
```

This code here

> https://codesandbox.io/s/4z1m9

But in javascript, I don't know how I show that grid..

> https://codepen.io/cms010621/pen/vYNqapG

This is the best idea in my head, but not working,, I don't know.. help me..

Answer (score 0):

- if you want to complete in this path you have to customize grid popup itself it's a long-hard way.
- you can hack and use new [dxPopup](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxPopup/) with your custom content which is grid maybe or forms or whatever components, and config this popup component to accept the data as a props. then at grid you can go with this steeps minimized the popup and passing the data [devextreme datagrid command button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605382/devextreme-datagrid-command-button/61592570#61592570).